# Logstash-5.6.0 and Elastic Search-6.2.1

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have the below configuration in logstash.conf,
Started my logstash with the following command `

```
logstash --verbose -f D:\ELK\logstash-5.6.0\logstash-5.6.0\logstash.conf`
```

and Elastic search is running at 9200 port but logstash is not pipelining the parsed log file contents into elastic search. did i miss any configuration ? or what am i doing wrong here.

```
input{
    file{
        path => "D:/server.log" start_position=> "beginning" type => "logs"
    }
    }
filter{
    grok{
        match => {'message'=>'\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtime}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}\[(?<threadname>[^\]]+)\]%{SPACE}%{WORD}\:%{WORD}\:%{WORD}%{SPACE}\(%{WORD:className}\.%{WORD}\:%{WORD}\)%{SPACE}\-%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:errorDescription}'
                  'message1'=>'\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtime}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}\[(?<threadname>[^\]]+)\]%{SPACE}%{WORD}\:%{WORD}\:%{WORD}:%{WORD}%{SPACE}\(%{WORD:className}\.%{WORD}\:%{WORD}\)%{SPACE}\-%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:errorDescription}'
                  'message2'=>'\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtime}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}\[(?<threadname>[^\]]+)\]%{SPACE}\(%{WORD:className}\.%{WORD}\:%{WORD}\)%{SPACE}\-%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:errorDescription}'
        }
        add_field => {
            'eventName' => 'grok'
        }   
        }
    }
output{
        elasticsearch{
            hosts=>["localhost:9200"] 
            index=>"tuesday"
        }
}
```

here is my sample log content :

```
[2018-02-12 05:25:22,996] ERROR [VBH-1]  (ClassA.java:55) - Could not process a new task
[2018-02-13 08:02:24,690] ERROR [CTY-2] C:31:cvbb09:0x73636711c67k4g2e (ClassB.java:159) - Calling command G Update on server http://localhost/TriggerDXFGeneration?null failed because server responded with http status 400 response was: ?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
[2018-02-13 08:02:24,690] DEBUG [BHU-2] C:31:cvbb09:0x73636711c67k4g2e (ClassC.java:836) - insertDxfProcessingQueue() called with ConfigID : FTCC08_0X5A3A7E222DD2171B
[2018-02-13 08:07:51,087] ERROR [http-apr-50101-exec-2] C:10:cvbb09 (ClassD.java:133) - Exception on TestScheduler():
```

It is failing to parse the log content.

```
{
          "path" => "D://ELK/server.log",
    "@timestamp" => 2018-02-19T16:01:12.083Z,
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "AAEINBLR05971L",
       "message" => "[2018-02-13 08:02:24,690] DEBUG [BHU-2] C:31:cvbb09:0x73636711c67k4g2e (ClassC.java:836) - insertDxfProcessingQueue() called with ConfigID : FTCC08_0X5A3A7E222DD2171B\r",
          "type" => "logs",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ]
}
```

Comment: you are performing filter operation, can you put ` stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }` under `output`, to print some logs

Comment: @PavanKumarJorrigala failed to parse the log content .

Comment: {
          "path" => "D://ELK/server.log",
    "@timestamp" => 2018-02-19T16:01:12.083Z,
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "AAEINBLR05971L",
       "message" => "[2018-02-13 08:02:24,690] DEBUG [BHU-2] C:31:cvbb09:0x73636711c67k4g2e (ClassC.java:836) - insertDxfProcessingQueue() called with ConfigID : FTCC08_0X5A3A7E222DD2171B\r",
          "type" => "logs",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "_grokparsefailure"
    ]
}

Comment: _grokeparsefailure, its patter issue, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37682250/4891892) may be useful to fix your pattern

Comment: You're trying to match more than one pattern to the same log (which is a good idea). But you've made a syntax error, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28453382/6113627

Comment: Your grok pattern should be written `grok {
  match => ["message", "pattern1", "pattern2", ..., "patternN"]
}`